# C++: Time to compile a global array

Tags: c++, arrays, compilation, global-variables

Using g++ 4.2.1 to compile, and just this very simple code, why does this code

```
int a[1000000000] = {0};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

take longer to compile than this

```
int a[10] = {0};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

if in C++ an array is not constructed during compile time?

and also, I saw that this code:

```
    int a[1000000000];

    int main()
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

(without the = {0}) does not take long to compile, is so fast as int a[10] = {0}

Comment: Where do you think `a` is allocated? When do you think it's created? Do you think it has an impact on the executable size? Have you tested this? Hint: You're declaring a very large statically allocated variable. This is substantially different from `int a*` which you allocate dynamically.

Comment: @tadman i just edited the question, check that even with a big array, without the ={0} it is fast to compile

Comment: without the `= {0};` your compiler probably optimizes it out since it's not used...

Comment: without the `={0}` no initialization code is required. Depending on how that array is being initialized by the compiler, for example is it making a 1000000000 array inside the executable file and taking a reasonable amount of time to write this massive file?

Comment: @samuelnj my friend made a test with -O0 to avoid the optimization, still taking long than the other.

Comment: I observed a big time difference on clang++ 3.4-1 (Linux, X64, using the -O0 flag): it takes 0.1 seconds (generating an executable with 7KB) to compile the first version of the program and 3 seconds (generating an executable with 9KB) to compile the second one on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
int a[100000000] = {0};
```

should take longer to compile than

```
int a[10] = {0};
```

because there are more characters to parse.

However, the compilation time should be negligible.

There may be more time involved, if the compiler is creating a data segment with all those 0 instead of using an initialization loop.

The statement:

```
int b[100000000];
```

will be faster to compile than the preceding statements because the compiler does not have to emit code or data to initialize the array.

Comment: Aren't those 0's allocated during execution time?

Comment: Those 0's have to be placed into the array.  Two common methods are to place them into the data segment of the executable (so that they are copied during RTL initialization), or they can be generated via code.  Depends on the compiler.  However, the compiler will take time to emit the code or the data.

Answer (score 0):

Where are your evidence? Where are the details (like the compiler you are using)? Are you using just this code or this code inside something else? How many runs have you done to determine this?

To get to the answer: the only negligible performance difference will be in parsing the code - since there will be more symbols in the `int a[100000000] = {0};` example.

Taking a look at the generated assembly will provide the answer how the variable is allocated: `gcc -c -S main.c`:

```
        .file   "main.c"  
        .globl  a                                                                                                                                                                                              
        .bss                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        .align 32                                                                                                                                                                                              
        .type   a, @object                                                                                                                                                                                     
        .size   a, 4000000000                                                                                                                                                                                  
a:                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        .zero   4000000000                                                                                                                                                                                     
        .text                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        .globl  main                                                                                                                                                                                           
        .type   main, @function                                                                                                                                                                                
main:                                                                                                                                                                                                          
.LFB0:                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        .cfi_startproc                                                                                                                                                                                         
        pushq   %rbp                                                                                                                                                                                           
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16                                                                                                                                                                                 
        .cfi_offset 6, -16                                                                                                                                                                                     
        movq    %rsp, %rbp                                                                                                                                                                                     
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6                                                                                                                                                                                
        movl    $0, %eax                                                                                                                                                                                       
        popq    %rbp                                                                                                                                                                                           
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8                                                                                                                                                                                      
        ret                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        .cfi_endproc                                                                                                                                                                                           
.LFE0:                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        .size   main, .-main                                                                                                                                                                                   
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2)"                                                                                                                                                  
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

AND:

```
        .file   "main.c"                                                                                                                                                                                       
        .globl  a                                                                                                                                                                                              
        .bss                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        .align 32                                                                                                                                                                                              
        .type   a, @object                                                                                                                                                                                     
        .size   a, 40                                                                                                                                                                                                
a:                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        .zero   40                                                                                                                                                                                             
        .text                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        .globl  main                                                                                                                                                                                           
        .type   main, @function                                                                                                                                                                                
main:                                                                                                                                                                                                          
.LFB0:                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        .cfi_startproc                                                                                                                                                                                         
        pushq   %rbp                                                                                                                                                                                           
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16                                                                                                                                                                                 
        .cfi_offset 6, -16                                                                                                                                                                                     
        movq    %rsp, %rbp                                                                                                                                                                                     
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6                                                                                                                                                                                
        movl    $0, %eax                                                                                                                                                                                       
        popq    %rbp                                                                                                                                                                                           
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8                                                                                                                                                                                      
        ret                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        .cfi_endproc                                                                                                                                                                                           
.LFE0:                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        .size   main, .-main                                                                                                                                                                                   
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2)"                                                                                                                                                  
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: He's right. It does take a long time (x64 GCC 6.3, -std=c++11 -O2) with no change in emitted code. Which makes sense since `a` is global and being zeroed either way.